# Add the opacity to the background color of a row

Tags: html, css, row, opacity, transparent

[image: Project preview]

I wonder if anyone knows how to add the `opacity` *(semi-transparent)* to the `background-color` *(light grey)* in this row. I have a `background-image` I'd like to see through the grey. I added my HTML code below.

Thanks, I appreciate it,
Michelle.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row text-center bg-light py-5">
  <div class="col-lg-7 col-xl-8 align-content-center">
    <h4 class="pt-3">See how your story comes to life!</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-4">
    <a href="https://youtu.be/2ErTF_AO7lk" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Listen to a free story.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code was added to a snippet, with a Bootstrap cdn. Can you please add any additional css/html to demonstrate a minimal reproducible issue? You can add a background with a placeholder from placekitten.com to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Hi I am not to sure how to do that. I have added a screen shot of the area of the page hopefully this is helpful for you. I wanted the light grey area to be semi transparent. I wasn't sure how to code it to make it that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the `opacity` CSS property.

```css
.some_class { 
    opacity: .5;
}
```

You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).

The next way is to use an expanded color definition. This could be an 8-character `HEX` code or RGBA code.

```css
.some_color_hex { 
    background-color: #cccccc88; 
}

.some_color_rgba { 
    background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, .5); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, should I add to the html code for that light grey or row? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the style with `background: rgba(248,249,250,0.5) !important;`. The keyword `!important` is needed to overwrite the style set in bootstrap 4.

```css
body {
 background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row text-center bg-light py-5" style="background: rgba(248,249,250,0.5) !important;">
  <div class="col-lg-7 col-xl-8 align-content-center">
    <h4 class="pt-3">See how your story comes to life!</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-4">
    <a href="https://youtu.be/2ErTF_AO7lk" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Listen to a free story.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, for your help I appreciate it xx

Comment: glad that I am able to help